# How to point a GoDaddy subdomain to several Heroku apps with a trailing slash?

Tags: subdomain, godaddy, heroku

I purchased a domain from GoDaddy like so:

`www.mydomain.com`

I created a subdomain as well:

`demo.mydomain.com`

I want to display all of my live demos on the `demo.mydomain.com` site like this:

`demo.mydomain.com/project1`

`demo.mydomain.com/project2`

I'm using Heroku to deploy different apps, so I know in the GoDaddy panel I can point `demo.mydomain.com` to a specific location, is it possible to point it to a specific location like `demo.mydomain.com/project1`? Right now the project I have is just pointing to `demo.mydomain.com`, however I want multiple apps to be found off that subdomain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that, directly, from the GoDaddy control panel. You *can* use the control panel to obtain similar results, if you are willing to set slightly different operations. You can make multiple, uniquely named, subdomains for the different apps. You can add those domains to the `DNS Manager` under the `Domains` menu, then use the `Redirects` under the `Domains` menu to do a premenant redirect to that URI. I.e.: Add the subdomain `project1.demo` pointing to the main IP, then redirect `project1.demo.example.com` to `http://demo.example.com/project1`. The redirect requires a protocol, so you'll need to choose whether or not to use TLS for each one before hand.

Not sure of you exact requirements, so you may not need to go through all this. If your apps can be set to point to `demo.example.com/project1` as their root, then creating the directory `project1` under the location set as the root of `demo.example.com` and creating the subdomain `demo.example.com` in the normal method: `Subdomains` on the `Domains` menu, could be enough.

The way their system does things, if `demo.example.com` is set to have a root of `public_html/my_demo`, then `demo.example.com/project1` will load from `public_html/my_demo/project1`.

Comment: This is good information. I guess I'm not totally at the point where I'm going to be doing this, but I wanted to see if it was possible. Will keep this in mind.